# Can a Kendo Grid read a large batch of items and perform the paging locally?

Tags: rest, kendo-ui, grid

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a REST API to service a Kendo UI Grid.  Option #1 - use the REST API for paging, Option #2 - read the entire result set at once and have the Grid control handle the paging.

Here are the problems I've run into with both:

1) I pass the Page and PageSize parameters through the query string.  The service get them, queries the data model, and returns just the number of records requested (e.g. 50 items from page 4).  The problem is that the paging controls then shows *page size* for the number of items in the grid.  That is, if my page size is 50 and there are 3,000 records in the result set, the Grid shows a total 50 with a displays a single "page" button on Page 1.  How do you force the Kendo UI Grid to use the total number of records?  How do you do this without running the query twice (once for the total, a second time to apply the Skip and Take values)?

2) I only have 3,000 records, so it's really no big deal to read the whole data set, but each time I hit the 'page forward', I get a spinner and the request for the entire data set goes out again.  Is there any way to tell the Kendo Grid to suck down the entire set of 3,000 records, but locally page in chunks of, say, 50 items per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `serverPaging` to `false` so it won't make a server call everytime. It is possible to read all the 3000 data at one time and then just use paging on local data. Here's the demo.

```js
var data =  new kendo.data.DataSource({
  serverPaging: false,
  pageSize: 5, 
  data: [
   {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'A', Age: '10', Country: 'USA'}, 
   {firstName: 'Max', lastName: 'B', Age: '20', Country: 'UK'}, 
   {firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'C', Age: '77', Country: 'Russia'}, 
   {firstName: 'Raj', lastName: 'D', Age: '55', Country: 'France'}, 
   {firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'E', Age: '5', Country: 'Ghana'}, 
   {firstName: 'Stan', lastName: 'F', Age: '51', Country: 'USA'}, 
   {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'G', Age: '21', Country: 'India'}, 
   {firstName: 'Lily', lastName: 'H', Age: '30', Country: 'USA'}, 
 {firstName: 'Lal', lastName: 'B', Age: '20', Country: 'UK'}, 
 {firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'G', Age: '21', Country: 'India'},
        {firstName: 'Sean', lastName: 'G', Age: '47', Country: 'Aus'},
  ]
});

$('#grid').kendoGrid({
 dataSource: data, 
  columns: [
    {
      field: "firstName",
      title: "firstName",
      width: "120px"
    }, {
      field: "lastName",
      title: "lastName",
      width: "120px"
    }, {
      field: "Age",
      title: "Age",
      width: "120px"
    }, {
      field: "Country",
      title: "Country",
      width: "120px"
    }
  ],
  pageable: true,
  dataBound: function () {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
<title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
   </body>
```

Comment: you are right when you have 3000 value but if you have 200.000 value what you can do? The one solution is custom paging from sql

Comment: @saulyasar I would prefer to do server side paging any-day. But the answer is specific to OP's question and just to demonstrate the paging can be done locally as well. also, there are plenty of ways to achieve paging but this particular solution could be really helpful when you have data cached.